# Not able to download live server in vs code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I am not able to install live server in my vs code
When I enter live server in manage extension I am getting all the extensions except live server

Please provide me any way to install it

Answer (score -2):

All Steps :

1. Clear the temp folder.
2. Open Vs code editor and install live server extension.
3. Give all that permission to extension that is mandatory.
4. In last close Code Editor and Reopen.
5. Now it will work.